# LUA, Separar string com números em uma tabela!

Tags: lua, lua-table

Eu estou com um sistema de resgatar códigos, no caso eu colocaria em um arquivo texto algo assim:

```
HFGD65,{2454,2454},1,1
```

seria:

CÓDIGO para resgatar -- string
{items} -- itens dentro da tabela em numeros
points -- numeros
days -- numero

ai eu abro:
por exemplo

```
local file = 'data/logs/codes.txt'
local f = io.open(file, "rb")
    for k, v in pairs(f) do
 -- retorna aquela linha
end
```

e eu uso

```
local v = ":JH2F36;:{{2173,1},{2160,2}};:0;:1;"
local var = v:gsub(':', ''):explode(';')
```

pra poder separar, mas então eu tenho que usar no arquivo txt assim:

```
:JH2F36;:{{2173,1},{2160,2}};:0;:1;
```

tem algum jeito diferente de chamar essa linha?

sendo que o código teria que retornar string e os mais em números?

se eu separar por "," quando checa a tabela corta no meio e termina ali.

queria simplifica e achar um jeito de colocar o código por exemplo:

```
HB7S5S;{2173,2160}:1:1
```

como são 4 itens ali /\ separar por ":"

a primeira retornaria string(o codigo) -- HB7S5S

e os demais(3) retornaria:

numeros:

(tabela)

1

1

Comment: Já cogitou a utilização de expressões regulares?

Comment: Eu não sei usar, não sei se teria um jeito de me explicar como fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Você pode separar a cadeia com a função [string.gmatch()](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin)**

```
function separa(s, delimitador)
tab = {};
for valores in (s..delimitador):gmatch("(.-)"..delimiter) do
    table.insert(tab, valores);
end
return result;
end
```

**Ou com a função [string.match():](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial)**

```
function Separa(Cadeia)
     local res = {}
     for pares in string.match(Cadeia, "[^;]+")
     -- aqui também pode ler a linha inteira: "[^\r]*"
     do
        local eq = string.find(pares, "=")
        if eq 
        then
           local chave = pares:sub( 1, eq-1)
           local valor = pares:sub(eq+1,eq+8)

        end
     end
  end
```